# How to configure PyInstaller to pass options to the interpreter without modifying the spec file?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I want to create an executable that sets some of the [run time python options](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#giving-run-time-python-options).

This can be done by editing the spec file (as described in the documentation linked above), but since I am building the executable through a script on a CI server, I can't manually edit the spec file. I also don't see a command line option for PyInstaller itself that would allow me to enable the interpreter options.

So, is there a good way to tell PyInstaller to pass command-line options to the Python interpreter, without manually modifying the spec file?